# Power Query delayed recursion

Tags: powerquery, m

I'm very new to Power Query and trying to piece a little demo together in Excel.

I have two web endpoints: I have to post some content to the first endpoint, this gives me the url of the second endpoint and then I have to query this second endpoint for the actual results. The second endpoint gives back a json response and in it, there is a field that represents if the results are ready or not. If the results are ready, they can be processed, if not, the endpoint should be queried again at a later date.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
let   
    apikey      = "MYAPIKEY",        
    proxyendpoint = "URL OF THE FIRST ENDPOINT",
    bytesbody   = File.Contents("FILE TO POST"),
    headers     = [#"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = apikey],
    bytesresp   = Web.Contents(proxyendpoint, [Headers=headers, Content=bytesbody]),    
    jsonresp    = Json.Document(bytesresp),    
    opLoc       = jsonresp[OperationLocation],
    getResult = (url) =>
        let           
           linesBody = Web.Contents(url, [Headers=headers]),
           linesJson = Json.Document(linesBody),
           resultStatus = linesJson[status],
           linesData = if (resultStatus = "Succeeded") then
                              linesJson[recognitionResult][lines]
                       else 
                              Function.InvokeAfter(()=>@getResult(url),#duration(0,0,0,5))
       in
          linesData,
   linesText = List.Transform(getResult(opLoc), each _[text]),   
   table = Table.FromList(linesText)
in
   table
```

My problem is that when I check with Fiddler, I see the second endpoint queried once, I can check there in the response that the results are not ready, the data loading "hangs", but I cannot see any additional calls to the second endpoint, so basically my recursive calls are not being evaluated.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my code was basically right. The issue was that `Web.Contents()` does some internal caching, that's why I couldn't see any more calls in Fiddler and that's why my data loading "hang" (since the first time the recursion exit criterion was false and the result got cached, every subsequent recursion just used the same data).

I created some POCs for the delayed recursion scenario and strangely, everything worked. I changed things around until I reached a version of the POC where the only difference was the `Web.Contents()` call. So I did a search for this specific issue and found a post [here](https://blog.crossjoin.co.uk/2017/01/06/web-contents-caching-and-the-excludedfromcachekey-option-in-power-bi-and-power-query/).

So as suggested in this post, I added a new header value to every `Web.Contents()` call to avoid the response being cached (also cleaned up the code a bit):

```
let   
    apikey      = "MYAPIKEY",   
    proxyendpoint = "URL OF THE FIRST ENDPOINT",
    bytesbody   = File.Contents("FILE PATH TO BE POSTED"),
    headers     = [#"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = apikey],
    bytesresp   = Web.Contents(proxyendpoint, [Headers=headers, Content=bytesbody]),    
    jsonresp    = Json.Document(bytesresp),    
    opLoc = jsonresp[OperationLocation],  
    getResult = (url, apiKeyParam) =>
      let
        // note the extra header here, which is different in every call
        currentHeaders = [#"Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key" = apiKeyParam, #"CacheHack" = Number.ToText(Number.Random())],
        linesBody = Web.Contents(url, [Headers=currentHeaders]),
        linesJson = Json.Document(linesBody),
        resultStatus = linesJson[status],
        result = if (resultStatus = "Succeeded") then linesJson[recognitionResult][lines]
                 else Function.InvokeAfter(()=>@getResult(url, apiKeyParam), #duration(0,0,0,5))
       in result,
    linesText = List.Transform(getResult(opLoc, apikey), each _[text]),   
    table = Table.FromList(linesText)    
 in table
```

Comment: Consider using the IsRetry option in Web.Contents, which will explicitly ignore the cache.

Comment: Awesome, this is what I needed, just wasn't precise enough when reading the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

With the **()=>** in the first argument of Function.InvokeAfter, the result of Function.InvokeAfter will be the function getResult, rather than the result from getResult. So it should be left out:

```
Function.InvokeAfter(@getResult(url),#duration(0,0,0,5))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem - I still cannot see any more requests made to the second endpoint. Something did change though, because now after a while I get a stackoverflow error.

Comment: Hard to say without the ability to test. My suggestion would be to create a test version with a counter and stop the iterations after e.g. 10 times.
Also add a list with the result statuses of each iteration and have that output instead of linesJson[recognitionResult][lines].

Comment: Turns out the issue was related to caching. Also, please note that you do need the ()=> in the first argument. I think this way it still returns the results of getResult, becase it is actually called.